# Group algebras. 

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebras

Given a group $G$. Let $\mathbb{C}$ be the complex field. Then $\mathbb{C}G$ is the set of linear combinations of elements of $G$. Addition and multiplication are defined as usual. We can also think $\mathbb{C}G$ as the set of all functions from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Addition is the addition of functions and multiplication of two functions is their convolution.

Now if we are give an algebraic group $G$ and $N$ is a subgroup of $G$. I saw the notation in many places. For example, [cluster algebras and representation theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.4552). Why $\mathbb{C}[N]$ is called coordinate ring of $N$? What are the elements of $\mathbb{C}[N]$? What are the additions and multiplications in $\mathbb{C}[N]$. Thank you very much.

Comment: nitpick :In my understanding, $\mathbb CG$ is the set of all functions from G to $\mathbb C$ _with finite support_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that paper $\mathbb C[N]$ denotes the ring of regular functions (also known as the coordinate ring) on the subgroup $N\subset G$, the maximal unipotent subgroup. $N$ is an affine variety, so this makes sense.

If you do not know what "coordinate ring" means, you *should* go read some introduction to algebraic geometry (I would suggest the wonderful *Ideals, varieties and algorithms* by David Cox, John Little and Donal O'Shea, or if you are only interested in algebraic groups, maybe T. A. Springer's *Linear Algebraic Groups* which is written so as to be (more or less) self-contained—YMMV, of course!), for otherwise it is most likely that Leclerc's paper is going to be pretty much incomprehensible...

You should keep in mind that «we can also think $\mathbb CG$ as the set of all functions from G to $\mathbb C$» only when the group $G$ is finite (and I would add that while you *may* think that you probably shouldn't) In Leclerc's context this is quite not the case.